# Lyx Beamer enumerate eating first letters of text in Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, lyx, lists, enumerate

In Lyx beamer environment, `enumerate` is not compiling properly: the balls overlay the first letters of the item text, and the numbers are to the left of the balls (and invisible because they're white on white--confirmed by changing color). This does not occur when my preamble only contains `\usetheme{Madrid}` but it does occur when I add the code I have found to reduce space between displayed equations. I am not aware of any other way to globally reduce space between displayed equations.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Problem slide]

Here is the code from my Lyx document that generates this image:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file.
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usetheme{Madrid}

% Code to reduce space between displayed equations
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{2pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2pt}
}

\end_preamble

\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout BeginFrame
Testing
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Elephant
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Zebra
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Jaguar
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Want less space between display equations
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
y=a+bx
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
and
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
z=d+rw
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
ending here.
\end_layout

\begin_layout EndFrame

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: As with all lyx questions (in my point of view): The internal (hidden) settings are quite difficult to interprete if no example is given

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? I don't know what you mean by "example." Example of what?

Comment: @user43953 http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @user43953 Note that .lyx files are just text files. You can open them with a text editor, copy the text, and paste it in here. Please read the information on the link above.

Comment: Ok thank you for advice, I revised the post. Let me know if this is still not the right way to post.

Comment: Please indent the code by 4 spaces, or highlight it and press the '{}' button: it will be more readable.

Comment: @user43953 thanks for the example. I can now reproduce. You should also produce a minimal example `.tex` file (in LyX go to File > Export) and post that here. There are many people here who do not use LyX, and this really comes down to a LaTeX question (because you are using preamble code).

Answer (score 1):

This occurs in an equivalent ordinary LaTeX document that includes your space reducing code:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{2pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Testing}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Elephant
  \item Zebra
  \item Jaguar
  \end{enumerate}

  Want less space between display equations
  \[
    y=a+bx
  \]
  and
  \[
    z=d+rw
  \]
  ending here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The bad placement is an artefact of spurious spaces at the ends of lines in your `\g@addto@macro`.  You should comment out each end of line as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

This then fixes your output:

[image: Corrected output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{2pt}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Testing}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Elephant
  \item Zebra
  \item Jaguar
  \end{enumerate}

  Want less space between display equations
  \[
    y=a+bx
  \]
  and
  \[
    z=d+rw
  \]
  ending here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Without the comment characters, each call to `\normalsize` inserts four spaces (one for each newline).  As the bullet item calls `\normalsize` there is space inserted before the labels moving them right, and consequently making them overlap the item text.

See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/15925) for a discussion of percent characters at the end of lines.